# Matplotlib: line length in .svg export

Tags: python, matplotlib, svg, inkscape

I'm drawing a polygon in matplotlib and exporting it in .svg so I can use it in eg. Inkscape. I know you can specify the image size in inches, but I'd like to have a line with length "1" to be mapped to a line with length 1 inch when opened in Inkscape.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.close('all')

f,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(3,3))
plt.plot([0,1],[0,0])
ax.axis('off')
plt.gca().set_position([0, 0, 1, 1])
ax.set_aspect('equal')
plt.savefig("line.svg")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear what `ax.set_aspect('equal')` would do here. So I'd remove that.
Next, what you need to do is to have the axis coordinate system synchronized to the figure size.

At this point it's unclear from the question what exactly you are trying to do.

- **Create a 3 inch figure with a 3 inch long line**
  Let the coordinate system go from 0 to 1, remove any margin inside the axes.

  ```
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

  f,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(3,3))
  plt.plot([0,1],[0,0])
  ax.axis('off')
  plt.gca().set_position([0, 0, 1, 1])
  ax.margins(0)
  plt.savefig("line.svg")
  ```

  or let the coordinate system go from 0 to 3, make the line 3 units long.

  ```
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

  f,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(3,3))
  plt.plot([0,3],[0,0])
  ax.axis('off')
  plt.gca().set_position([0, 0, 1, 1])
  ax.set_xlim(0,3)
  plt.savefig("line.svg")
  ```
- **Create a 3 inch figure with a 1 inch long line**
  Let the coordinate system go from 0 to 1, create a line of 1/3 units in length

  ```
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

  f,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(3,3))
  plt.plot([0,1/.3],[0,0])
  ax.axis('off')
  plt.gca().set_position([0, 0, 1, 1])
  ax.set_xlim(0,1)
  plt.savefig("line.svg")
  ```

  or let the coordinate system go from 0 to 3 and create a line of 1 unit length.

  ```
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

  f,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(3,3))
  plt.plot([0,1],[0,0])
  ax.axis('off')
  plt.gca().set_position([0, 0, 1, 1])
  ax.set_xlim(0,3)
  plt.savefig("line.svg")
  ```

  This last approach seems to be the most intuitive one, but since it's not too clear from the question how the size in inches of the figure should relate to the axes units, I provided all possible solutions.